# Occasional Spinning Sound When Clutch Pedal Fully Depressed

Tags: transmission, clutch

I got my clutch changed just over 30,000 miles ago, as it was slipping badly in several gears. It was a 3-piece clutch kit (so I was told) by a reputable garage. I occasionally can hear a sort of "spinning" sound when I depress the clutch pedal to the floor as of this morning during my drive to work, however it disappeared when I used my car this afternoon again. Whilst the symptom is present, when putting it into gear, the engagement is aggressive and instant. I have a manual transmission. The symptom usually stays for maybe 5 minutes and then disappears for several days.

What could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hearing this when you press the clutch pedal to the floor (disengaging the clutch), the only thing which pops to mind is the throwout bearing. From your description, I doubt there is anything to worry about here. The throwout bearing is something which usually comes with a "clutch kit" and is something which should be changed *while you're in there*. This is regardless of whether it seems okay or not. It's a lot easier and cheaper to change it while you have the transmission out to change the clutch than it is not to.

Anyways, for your description alone, I doubt you have anything to worry about. As long as the clutch is engaging and disengaging it should be fine. If the engagement/disengagement points start to change or if you feel it start slipping again, I'd suggest them to worry about issues. Obviously, if the noise you are hearing comes back and stays, that would be another thing to worry about. At this point, it doesn't seem like there's too much going on.